# web site reponsivo, problema no CSS

Tags: html, css

Estava correndo tudo muito bem, mas me deparei com um problema no meu css..

Um é o meu footer, que mesmo eu mudando a cor do background ele fica com a cor do background do body

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu codigo css do topo da page:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800');
/* CSS Document */
body { 
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    margin: 0; }

.background
{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../images/fundo.png);
    background-position: top center;
    min-height:355px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    color: #000000;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;

}

.background .links ul {
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;

}

.background .links ul li {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;
}

.background .links ul li a {

    display: block;
    text-decoration:none; 
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#eeeeee;
}

.background .links ul li a:hover {
    color: #b0fafd;

}
```

o meu codigo css do meio/rodapé da page :

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300|Lato:400,300,700);
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum:400,400i,700,700i');
h1 {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #063960;
}
h2 {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #00cafd;
}
.backk
{
min-height: 42px;
position: relative;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#110851+0,110851+39,cf0404+100 */
background: #110851; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #110851 0%, #110851 39%, #cf0404 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #110851 0%,#110851 39%,#cf0404 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #110851 0%,#110851 39%,#cf0404 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#110851', endColorstr='#cf0404',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}

.row
{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../images/faq.png); 
    background-position: top center;
    height:auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    color: #000000;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.row h2
{
color: #e2aba7;
font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 48px;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.row p
{
    margin: auto;
    width: 960px;
    font-family: Oswald;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.faq .faqq
{

    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height:97px;
    width: 97px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 35px;

}
.rodape1
{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #10101d;
    position: relative;
    max-height:160px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    background-size: cover;

}
.logo-rodape{
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 60px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 5px;

}
.texto{
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin:auto;
    font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.texto p
{
    color: #878888;
}
.direitos
{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #161625;
    color: #000000;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative; 
    background-size: cover;
}
.textoo {
    color: #dd8f89;

    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 20px;

}
.textoo p{
    color:#878888;
}
.textoo h3{
    color: #063960;
}
```

Comment: essa do attachment ninguém ajudou, e então como eu estava com esse problema no css aproveitei pra postar ela junto novamente.

Comment: Gabriel, considere esperar ou ganhar pontos de reputação para oferecer uma recompensa a sua pergunta, aumentando as chances de alguém responde-la. Faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) E também leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas) Pois é bem provável que ninguém responda mesmo suas perguntas, pois você está usando o site de modo inadequado. Postando respostas como comentários, fazendo perguntas que já fez antes...

Comment: ok vou apagar a parte do attachment .

Comment: Mas vocês poderiam me ajudar na primeira pergunta ali?

Comment: se vc responder a pergunta que fiz lá, eu até poderia ajudar.

Comment: opa foi mal é pq eu criei outra conta .

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar com essa parte do foorter?

Comment: É que o footer não vai até à parte de baixo da janela, por isso fica uma faixa. Vc quer que o footer ocupe até a parte de baixo da janela?

Comment: Tipo eu tou querendo deixar reponsivo, mas qnd eu diminuo o zoom pro menor possível aparece a cor q eu botei no fundo do background do boddy em baixo do meu footer com os direitos autorias e etc.

Comment: mt obrigado mano só por uma resposta ai q eu voto nela e na outra lá também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar esse tipo de problema, sugiro colocar uma cor de fundo para cada seção, e setar uma cor de fundo no `body` que será também a cor de fundo do rodapé.

Veja o esquema:

```css
html, body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background: red;
}

header{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background: yellow;
   float: left;
}

main{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   background: #777;
   float: left;
}

footer{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<header>
   header
</header>
<main>
   <p>conteúdo</p>
</main>
<footer>
   footer
</footer>
```

Desta forma dará a impressão de que o rodapé ocupa o resto de baixo da página caso sobre espaço.

Comment: vlw mano, mt obrigado!